# How to fix NetBeans 12.0 and Maven 3.6.3 error

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I have installed NetBeans 12.0 64 bit on windows 10, after installing NetBeans I have an error in Maven. i tried to figure it out but I couldn't solve it. I am a beginner who follows java as a first programming language. Please help
JDK 11 installed
NetBeans 12.0 installed
Maven 3.6.3 install(default with NetBeans installing)
**system error>**

**Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to internal-repository (http://repo.mycompany.com/proxy): Transfer failed for http://repo.mycompany.com/proxy/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom: Unknown host No such host is known (repo.mycompany.com) -> [Help 1]**
**screenshots>**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAYcP.jpg)

I have changed the settings.xml by using this guidelines
`https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html`

Comment: Upgrade Netbeans as well as Maven ...

Comment: Unknown host No such host is known (repo.mycompany.com)  - fix that

Answer (score -1):

Use the latest version of NetBeans https://netbeans.apache.org/download/index.html.
Version 12.0 is outdated and not supported.

Comment: I appreciate about your concern 

Comment: How would that fix an unknown host?

Comment: Your suggestion would be fine if posted as a comment, but does nothing to address the specific issue that the user is facing, and does not rise to the level of being a constructive answer.